# How to sort descending using PowerShell called from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, parameters

I am calling PowerShell from C# and adding a Sort-Object as such:

```
powerShell.AddCommand("Sort-Object");
powerShell.AddParameter("Property", SortObject);
```

I can't figure out how to sort in Descending order. I have tried `"User Descending"`, `"User -Descending"`, `"User;Descending"`, and so on, but it ignores whatever I put in. What am I missing?

I think my confusion is that I am sorting on multiple fields. So this works:

```
powerShell.AddCommand("Sort-Object");
powerShell.AddParameter("Property", "ID");
powerShell.AddParameter("Descending");
```

But to sort on multiple fields I do something like this:

```
object[] SortObject1 = { "ID", "TimeCreated" };
powerShell.AddCommand("Sort-Object");
powerShell.AddParameter("Property", SortObject1);
```

So I need to tell it that one field is ascending and one descending. How would I do that.

This is my first post to StackOverflow so please excuse procedural ignorance.

Comment: You say you have tried adding `-Descending` but have not provided code examples for it. Please provide the code, as details matter here.

Comment: Also I have never done this but if you have to add the Property parameter, wouldn't it be logical that you would have to add the Descending parameter?

Comment: The [Microsoft documentation for `AddParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addparameter?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) literally has this as the example.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `Descending` property to the command as in:

```
powerShell.AddCommand("Sort-Object").
    AddParameter("Property", SortObject).  # assume this is the name of property to sort by
    AddParameter("Descending");
```